# How does OS route TCP packets of an established connection

Tags: linux, sockets, unix, networking, tcp

I'm confused about how TCP packets are routed on the OS level after TCP connection has been established.

Suppose a sever is listening passively on a TCP port for incoming traffic. The server receives a connection request, accepts it, and created a socket for `source_ip:port` and destination_ip:port, e.g. (`x.x.x.x:9999, 127.0.0.1:8080`).

How are subsequent packets sent from `x.x.x.x:9999` to `127.0.0.1:8080` routed on the server? Does the OS route them to the process binding port 8080, which in turn routes them to file descriptor with source `x.x.x.x:9999`? If yes, does this mean that each application much implement logic to route packets of established connections to the appropriate file descriptor?

Or does the OS route them directly to the open socket? If yes, how does the OS know which socket to route to since incoming request use well known port number (8080 in this case)?

Comment: The accept call creates a socket with source_ip:port and destination_ip:port and the more data for this connection will be directly delivered to this socket. Everything of this is in the kernel, nothing in the application (unless user space networking is used of course).

Comment: Afaik, all packets, handshake and subsequent packets after connection is established, are addressed to the server's listening port (8080 in my example). How does the OS know which socket to route incoming packets? Does it maintain a mapping of `source_ip:source_port, destination_ip:destination_port(listening port)` to  socket?

Comment: Of course.  Just do a netstat or similar command on a system and you see all the sockets with local and foreign address.